# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete No Cells Found

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete anything in column B that has a blank in it. A1:A10 = {3,1,10,1,1,10,2,2,2,10}. When I run my code I get a error at the delete row line. It's a "runtime 1004 error, no cells found." There clearly should have been some cells found. What is going on? I have seen some people suggest putting an On Error clause around the delete row, but that just results in nothing getting deleted.

```
Sub test()
Dim Total_Rows As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Total_Rows = 10
Range("B1", "B" & Total_Rows) = "=if(A1=10,"""",1)"
Range("B1", "B" & Total_Rows).Copy
Range("B1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Set rng = Range("B1", "B" & Total_Rows)
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rng.AutoFilter 1, "="
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False '~~> removes the filter
```

This filter out blanks or zero length strings then deletes it.
Or you can directly filter `A1:A10` like this:

```
Range("A1:A10").AutoFilter 1, 10
Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution. What does the 1, 10 mean after autofilter?

Comment: 1 is for field argument, 10 is for criteria1 argument. Did it work for you?

Comment: It did except the first row is always deleted no matter the value. Also any documentation of field arguments vs.  Critical arguments? I'm not familiar with those terms.

Comment: @user2242044 those are the arguments' names, so the documentation is to be found in the documentation for the AutoFilter method.   For example, the criteria1 argument (that is, "criteria" plus the numeral "1", not "critical") specifies the criteria for the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looping through the range like below

```
For Each cell In rng     
   If cell.Value = "" Then cell.EntireRow.Delete    
Next cell
```

instead of finding a blank cell

Comment: I had that originally but the actual file has 3000 rows so this was very slow.